# Auto Import Script not Working

Tags: vbscript

I'm an absolute beginner with VB hence I might ask some silly questions.
I have a VB script getting triggered via a Batch file which results in data being imported for last day.
Below is the code for VB and Batch file.
Please let me know if you see any error in the code.

**VB Script**

```
rem 
rem XLink_Import.vbs
rem 

Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 

' filename = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("today_xlink.bat") 
' Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.fileSystemObject") 
' Set oFile = objFileSystem.CreateTextFile(filename, TRUE) 

Dim i
Dim ImportStartOffset, ImportedNumberOfDays

If WScript.Arguments.length > 0 Then
    For i=0 to WScript.Arguments.length-1
        Arg = WScript.Arguments(i)
        If Left(Arg,1) = "-" Then
            If ( Arg = "-o" ) Then
                ImportStartOffset = WScript.Arguments(i+1) 
            End if
            If ( Arg = "-n" or Arg = "-l" ) Then
                ImportedNumberOfDays = WScript.Arguments(i+1) 
            End if
        End if
    Next
End If

rem Prepare the import start date

Dim Dy, Mth
Dim ImportDate
ImportDate = Now + ImportStartOffset
Dy = Day(ImportDate) 
Mth = Month(ImportDate) 
If Len(Dy) = 1 Then Dy = "0" & Dy 
If Len(Mth) = 1 Then Mth = "0" & Mth 
ImportStartDate = Dy & "/" & Mth & "/" & Year(ImportDate) 

rem Prepare import script to run (not useed yet)
rem oFile.WriteLine("isps_ul.exe -t -d " & todaydate & " -L 1") 
rem oFile.Close

rem Run XLink import

wscript.echo "isps_ul.exe -t -d " & ImportStartDate & " -L " & ImportedNumberOfDays
oShell.Run "isps_ul.exe -t -d " & ImportStartDate & " -L " & ImportedNumberOfDays, 1, true
```

**Batch File**

```
@echo off
rem
rem XLink_Import.bat
rem
rem Manually starts an Xlink import starting today + a StartOffset of some days. 
rem Imported number of days can also be set.
rem

set ImportStartOffset=0
set ImportedNumberOfDays=1

cscript XLink_Import.vbs -o %ImportStartOffset% -n %ImportedNumberOfDays%

pause
```

Comment: do you get an error while running your script ? if so, which and at what line ? why the batch, you can do the configuration in the script itself or using parameters form the command line ? you should also assign the run string to a variable to be DRY.

Comment: Hi @peter - Thanks for your reply, No I don't get an error, I get the message " isps_ul.exe -t -d28/11/2016 -L"  Reason for using batch is that I want to automate this job and the only way I know is using windows task scheduler.I'm sorry but I understand the DRY part(Please forgive my ignorance I just started)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need both a batch and a script, one of either would be enough, doing the whole thing in batch would require with some suggling with special parameters and I'm not into that so I'll adapt your script a bit like below.
Since you keep your 2 confiuration variables in the windows environment you can read them from vbscript as well, other option would be to read from a configuration file, from the command line like you did or keep the in the script itself.

Your middle part, makig sure the date is speleld correct could be omitted if you set those dates correctly in the configuration (environmentvariables).

If your import is going to work you should check before by running what is displayed as command, so eg `"eisps_ul.exe -t -d28/11/2016 -L"` should run, otherwise search on that problem first.

What I meant in my comment about being DRY means you should not repeat things, in case of your command you can store the concatenated command in a variable and use that for viewing and running.

```
Dim ImportStartOffset, ImportedNumberOfDays, oShell, command, Dy, Mth, ImportDate, ImportStartDate
Constant WaitOnReturn = true, WindowStyle = 1 '1 = Activate and display

'read configuration environment variables
Set oShell           = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
ImportStartOffset    = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%ImportStartOffset%" )
ImportedNumberOfDays = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%ImportedNumberOfDays%" )

'Prepare the import start date (not necessary if environmentvariables would be configured well)
ImportDate = Now + ImportStartOffset
Dy = Day(ImportDate) 
Mth = Month(ImportDate) 
If Len(Dy) = 1 Then Dy = "0" & Dy 
If Len(Mth) = 1 Then Mth = "0" & Mth 
ImportStartDate = Dy & "/" & Mth & "/" & Year(ImportDate) 

'Run XLink import
command = "isps_ul.exe -t -d " & ImportStartDate & " -L " & ImportedNumberOfDays
wscript.echo command
oShell.Run command, WindowStyle, WaitOnReturn
Set oShell = Nothing
```

Comment: Hi @peter,Thanks a lot for your help I will try to incorporate this into the code.